Disable docker-desktop logging
Those logs located in <docker folder>/desktop/log/host/ (for me it's ~/.docker/desktop/log/host/) and named like: electron-<year>-<month>-<day>-<hour>.log.<some number>. Over time each of those files can grow up to 20 MB!
Yet, I understand that I can write some crontab script myself, I wonder, can it be disabled, or, at least, can I tell to docker-desktop to clear this folder over time itself.

Tried to set {"log-driver": "none"} inside of daemon.json file.

The log-driver setting in daemon.json only affects the docker daemon and container logs. Those electron logs sound like they are related to the docker desktop ui.
